# cabal version 3.2: unrecognised command: sandbox (try --help)

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, haskell-platform

Following this tutorial http://wiki.haskell.org/How_to_write_a_Haskell_program#Recommended_tools but not able to run `cabal sandbox init`. I have the latest version of cabal installed on my Mac and installed via instructions from https://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html

```
cabal sandbox init
    cabal: unrecognised command: sandbox (try --help)
```

```
cabal --version
    cabal-install version 3.2.0.0
    compiled using version 3.2.0.0 of the Cabal library
```

Anyone run into the same issue and know the fix to use sandbox with cabal?

Comment: You don't.  Sandboxes are deprecated and no longer available in cabal.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: Maybe explain why it is not needed any more, what to do instead and turn your comment into an answer that way?

Comment: Most of the stuff from the Haskell wiki can be significantly out of date. I'd suggest using an alternative resource to begin with.

Comment: The reason that sandboxes don't exist any more is that in recent versions of cabal all builds are effectively "sandboxed" or "hermetic" by default.